# can I connect MySQL database file .ibd located on desktop or any directory to java?

Tags: java

I would like to link java to different directory database folder like on desktop or any path,

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:C:\\Users\pc\Desktop\sample","root","root");
```

this code here work fine

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","root");
```

here is full code that I work on :

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class mysqlconnect {


    Connection conn=null;

    public static Connection ConncerDB(){

    try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");



        Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample", "root","root");



    } catch (Exception e){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);


                }


    }

}
```

by the end i would like to build project on java with MySQL database and I can run that project as .jar file and database can be still connected

Comment: Isn't MySQL a database "server"?  I didn't think you could just link to a directory or file, but instead needed to link to the "server" instead

Comment: I found somthing usefull here we have to add port for mysql  we have to add that port to Firewall windows I think outdoor or indoor i'm not sure 

https://www.brightfunction.co.uk/connecting-to-mysql-server-across-a-local-windows-network/